# X icon not clicked in active window in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

The following code is not working:

```
List<WebElement> close=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[@aria-label='Close' and @role='button' and @class='k-button k-bare k-button-icon k-window-action']"));
close.get(4).click();
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="k-window-titlebar k-header" style="margin-top: -28px;"
    <span id="relatedNumberWindow_wnd_title"class="k-window-title" Related   Numbers
    </span>
         <div class="k-window-actions" >
             <a class="k-button k-bare k-button-icon k-window-action" role="button" aria-label="Close" </a>
         </div>
</div>
```

I want to click on X icon (among minimize and Maximize for which code is not written above, else it will be too long) to close my active window.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: do you get some error? if yes please attach it. xpath seems legit.

Comment: No did not get nay error but it simple not clicking on X and automation gets terminated after that.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **X** icon you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.k-window-titlebar.k-header a.k-button.k-bare.k-button-icon.k-window-action[aria-label='Close']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='k-window-titlebar k-header']//a[@class='k-button k-bare k-button-icon k-window-action' and @aria-label='Close']")).click();
  ```